# Android: Custom Surface View crashing upon orientation change

Tags: android, xml, surfaceview

I was reading [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/another-exercise-of-surfaceview-in.html) on how to use a custom surface view class in an XML layout and when I ran the code, the app crashed when my phone's orientation changed. I've noticed a lot of examples involving custom threads and surface view subclasses crashing when the orientation changes, does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

```
09-25 18:19:40.639: E/Trace(4982): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-25 18:19:40.639: D/ActivityThread(4982): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
09-25 18:19:40.639: D/ActivityThread(4982): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
09-25 18:19:40.639: D/ActivityThread(4982): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
09-25 18:19:40.959: D/libEGL(4982): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
09-25 18:19:40.979: D/libEGL(4982): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
09-25 18:19:40.979: D/libEGL(4982): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
09-25 18:19:41.049: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(4982): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-25 18:19:41.099: E/(4982): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-25 18:19:41.099: E/(4982): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
09-25 18:19:41.099: D/OpenGLRenderer(4982): Enabling debug mode 0
09-25 18:19:58.127: W/dalvikvm(4982): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d46438)
09-25 18:19:58.147: E/AndroidRuntime(4982): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-156822
09-25 18:19:58.147: E/AndroidRuntime(4982): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 18:19:58.147: E/AndroidRuntime(4982):     at com.example.practicesurface.MySurfaceView.onDraw(MySurfaceView.java:129)
09-25 18:19:58.147: E/AndroidRuntime(4982):     at com.example.practicesurface.MySurfaceView$MySurfaceThread.run(MySurfaceView.java:39)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move this line of code:

```
thread = new MySurfaceThread(getHolder(), this);
```

from the init() method in MySurfaceView, to the surfaceCreated() method.

When shifting orientation, the onCreate methods are recalled, but the constructor of MySurfaceView won't be called, since it is retained.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be fixing the problem entirely. The app is crashing less now, but it still crashes if the orientation changes too much.

Comment: Well, im guessing that solved the problem you were having. I'm guessing it was an illegal state exception. What exception are you getting now? It sounds like an out of memory exception maybe?

Comment: 09-25 11:51:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(32098): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-154850
09-25 11:51:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(32098): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you need to post your logcat log.

Comment: interesting... something is going null in the onDraw method in MySurfaceView, but unless you edited the code in the example a lot, there shouldn't be much there... It's either the Canvas, or the Paint. Check to see what's becoming null. If it's the canvas, wrap the whole method in an if(canvas != null) statement. If it's the paint, quickly recreate the paint, or better yet, recreate the paint in the onSurfaceCreated method, rather than init / declaration line.

Comment: It looks like it was the canvas that was going null, not quite sure why that was but wrapping the method up in the (canvas != null) condition did the trick!